# How to update npm to latest version on Fedora

Tags: fedora, node.js, npm

I've try to run this:

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

to test [`npm audit`](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/running-a-security-audit), but this command failed, I've got error:

```
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fs-write-stream-atomic
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fs-write-stream-atomic'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fs-write-stream-atomic
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-06-04T16_50_00_242Z-debug.log
```

to restore the state I need to install npm using dnf (I need to remove the `npm` then `/usr/lib/node_modules` and install npm again).

if I move the file (it's symlink) then I've got error:

```
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'fs-write-stream-atomic'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-06-04T18_09_09_479Z-debug.log
```

How can I install npm 6 on Fedora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended up using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

after installation using

```
nvm install node
nvm use node
```

and I've got versions node v10.4.0 and npm v6.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might want to consider [`asdf`](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/). It's based on a plug-in system and installs ‒ sort of.

```
[gorre@uplink ~]$ asdf plugin-add nodejs
[gorre@uplink ~]$ bash ~/.asdf/plugins/nodejs/bin/import-release-team-keyring
[gorre@uplink ~]$ asdf install nodejs <version_here>
[gorre@uplink ~]$ asdf global nodejs <version_here>
```

> **NOTE:** All of that, provided you installed `asdf` previously.

You can install different versions and refer to them by specifying `local` in the particular directory that you would like. The basics is that it will create `.tool-versions` file that refers to that version, overwriting the other settings.

The bonus here is that `asdf` not only supports Node.js, but many other languages/platforms/toolkits, as well as maintaining, to some extent, the same capabilities of `nvm`.

Comment: I don't think I will use this since I already have nvm working but maybe it will help someone else.